# Merging two dataframes with different encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Can I read two datasets using different python encodings ("utf_8" and "ISO-8859-1") and then merge them?

Comment: Can you show a output of `df.dtypes` for both the table?

Comment: Please disregard the error. I updated the post just with the first question.

Comment: You will need to paste both the datasets, can't answer the question without that.